# Using Euclidean geometry, how to find $x$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

This question comes from a friend exam that I'm helping to review.
I've been trying hard but can't find the answer.

Using Euclidean geometry, how to find the angle $x$?

> [image: angle inside a kite]

I've been able to work out all the angles based on $x$ and $180^{\circ} $, but then I got stuck.

Here's my calculation:

I named the center point as $E$

$$ \angle ABD = 180^{\circ}  - 6x \\ 
   \angle ABC = 180^{\circ}  - 3x $$

$$\angle ABC = \angle ABD + \angle DBC \\
180^{\circ}  - 3x = 180^{\circ}  - 6x + \angle DBC $$

$$ \begin{align} \angle DBC &= 3x \\
\angle BEC &= 180^{\circ} - 4x\\
\angle BDC &= 180^{\circ} - 5x \end{align}$$

$$ \angle DEC = 180^{\circ} - \angle ACD - \angle BDC = 180^{\circ} - (x + 180^{\circ} - 5x) = 4x $$

Would anyone be able to help me with this question?

Comment: I'm worried the walls of my house may fall.

Comment: I've added the motivation and my steps so far. The question keeps getting automatically closed. What else am I missing?

Comment: *"The question keeps getting automatically closed."* Not quite. The question was closed *once*. It'll stay closed until it accumulates enough "reopen" votes from the community. This can take some time, so be patient. Adding your work is the proper thing to do to attract those votes.

Comment: OK, Thanks. It seems the question is open now.

Comment: I suppose there must be more simple solution. Using sine rule in $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle BCD$ gives $\sin 6x \sin 2x=\sin^2 3x$. Relevant solution is $x=15^\circ$.

Comment: This specific question asks for a solution using Euclidian geometry. Although your answer seems correct, I don't think is applicable here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\angle BAD=3x=\angle ADB$, hence $AB=BD$.

Let $E$ be the point on $AC$ such that $BE=AB$. Then $A,D,E$ lie on a circle with center $B$, hence $\angle EBD =2\angle EAD = 2x$.

On the other hand, $\angle AEB=\angle BAE=2x$, hence $\angle CBE=\angle AEB-\angle ACB=2x-x=x$.

We see that $\triangle CEB \sim \triangle CDA$ because these triangles have equal angles. In particular $\frac{CE}{CD}=\frac{CB}{CA}$. Since $\angle ACB=x=\angle DCE$, we have $\triangle ACB \sim\triangle DCE$ by SAS. Hence $\angle EDC =\angle BAC=2x$.

So $\angle DEA=\angle EDC+\angle DCE=2x+x=3x$. So $\angle DEB=\angle DEA+\angle AEB =3x+2x=5x$. Also $\angle BDE =\angle DEB=5x$ because $BD=BE$. We see now that the sum of angles of triangle $EBD$ equals $12x$. This leads to $12x=180^\circ$, hence $x=15^\circ$.

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is the correct path, but I don't get why you said:
"Then A,D,E lie on a circle with center B, hence ∠EBD=∠EAD=2x."
In fact, ∠EAD=x, not 2x.

Comment: @Ricarte Thanks, it was a typo. Should be $2\angle EAD$ instead of $\angle EAD$. The point is that the central angle equals two times the inscribed angle.

Comment: OK, that clears it up!

Answer (score 0):

As already shown, $BD=AB$, also since $\widehat{DAC}=\widehat{ACB}=x$ we infer $BC\parallel AD$, hence $\widehat{DBC}=\widehat{ADB}=3x$. Take $E$ reflection of $D$ about $BC$, it belongs to $AB$ and $BE=BD$, thus, since $AB=BD=BE$, $\widehat{ADE}=90^\circ$, thus $\widehat{CDE}=\widehat{CED}=90^\circ-2x$, thence the circumcenter of $\triangle CAE$ lies onto $ED$; with $AD=CD$ we infer that $D$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle CAE$, wherefrom $\widehat{BAD}=\widehat{BED}=45^\circ$, hence $3x=45^\circ, x=15^\circ$.

Best regards,[image]